# Facebook and Google Directions resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-maps

I'm trying to dynamically resize the facebook iFrame based on the length of the directions provided by the google maps api. So far, no luck.

I'm setting up the async resize in javascript

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () { FB.canvas.setAutoResize(); }
```

and the google maps directions panel is set up like this

```
directionsService.route( request, function (response, status) {
$('#directions_panel').setDirections(response); }
```

When I debug, the height of the directions panel (from jQuery's .height) has the value 0.

Comment: Does the directions panel contain floated elements?

Comment: @adam directions_panel is an empty div until google responds to my request - after that I don't know what they're putting in there

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: This is going to come off quite noob, but how?

I can't find where to post an answer to a question I asked.

Comment: @adauctus: Scroll to the bottom of this page. You should see a button labelled "Answer Your Question". It will ask you for confirmation and then show you a nice box to type your answer in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render', function (response) {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
});
```